# Как в Django ставить url в условие?

Tags: python, django

меня интересует, как можно сделать что-то типа:

**если юрл = "такой-то" то
делать это**

Comment: А зачем? Чем вам не угодил стандартный роутинг в Django?

Comment: например, если у меня перейти по ссылке, то кол-во товаров изменится, и есть кнопка, которая возвращает всё обратно и соответственно меняет адрес, но она же не должна висеть там всегда, поэтому я и хочу узнать, можно ли сделать так чтобы при нужном мне адресе эта кнопка исчезала.

Comment: Ничего не понятно, почему у вас в принципе есть какая-то связь между ссылкой и количеством и почему переход по ссылкам меняет количество? Это всё звучит сильно неправильно

Comment: Я имел ввиду фильтр товаров

Comment: Фильтр обычно подразумевает изменение QuerySet на основе параметров из query string, и эти параметры можно прочитать через `request.GET` во вьюхе

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Крутой конечно вопрос) как то так:

```
if url == "Такойто":
   urlpatterns = [
      path(url, делать это),
   ]
else:
   urlpatterns = [
    path(url, делать другое),
   ]
```

Comment: Благодарю!!!!!!

Comment: Что такое `url`, откуда его тут брать и вообще куда писать весь этот код?